# Error code: Inavlid in Loading Data on BigQuery

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, error-code

I have a large CSV file (nearly 10,000 rows) and I am trying to upload it on the BigQuery but it gives me this error:

ile-00000000: CSV table references column position 8, but line starting at position:622 contains only 8 columns. (error code: invalid)

Can anyone please tell me a possible to reason to it? I have double checked my Schema and it looks alright.

Thanks

Comment: Try a sample and see if works with 5 lines. If that works and the entire dataset is not, then somewhere you have a broken line. Let me know how it went with 5 lines?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, any solution? Because BigQuery shuffles lines (I presume) in some cases it can read LIMIT 10 lines from GSC. But in most cases it gives this error. My file in in CSV, it has double-quoted _entire_ field, but that should not be a problem.

Comment: It does not seem like a broken line either. I checked for control characters.

Comment: cat myfile.csv | grep '[[:cntrl:]]' - returns nothing

Comment: Given that you have double quotes involved, I'd wager something has gone wrong with escaping double quotes, leading to a string containing double quotes causing a split in the line data, or something of that kind. 

Have you run any check over the file to ensure its regular schema?

Comment: Is this issue still occurring? Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: If you found a solution, you should post it as a self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when trying to import a large data set in a csv to a BigQuery table.

The issue turned out to be some ascii control characters (\b, \t, \r, \n) in the data that was written in the csv. When the csv was being sent to BigQuery these characters caused the BiqQuery csv parser to misinterpret the line and break because the data didn't match with the number of columns in the header.

Replacing these characters with a space (to preserve formatting as best as possible) allowed me to import the data without further issues.

Comment: did you replaced before loading in jobconfig .is there any option like that

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the load job failed because at least one row has fewer columns than the automatically detected schema dictates.

Add

```
allow_jagged_rows=true
```

in the options.